# Access the fragment functions from fragment object generated at runtime

Tags: android-fragments

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {



    ArrayList <Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList <Fragment>();
    Fragment1 obj1=new Fragment1();
    Fragment2 obj2=new Fragment2();
    Fragment3 obj3=new Fragment3();
    Fragment4 obj4=new Fragment4();

    fragments.add(obj1);
    fragments.add(obj2);
    fragments.add(obj3);
    fragments.add(obj4);

    Fragment fragment = fragments.get(position);
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

So using these objects at the runtime through getItem() method I wanna access the functions in the fragments?So plz anyone help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast the fragment returned to the one you need to.

`YourClass fragmentGenerator = new YourClass();
((Fragment1)fragmentGenerator.getItem(0)).yourMethod1();
((Fragment2)fragmentGenerator.getItem(1)).yourMethod2();`